# Can I make a module from a bunch of single-function scripts?

Tags: powershell

We've accumulated a bunch of scripts, each looks and feels like CmdLets, i.e. it has a set of declared params and then it immediately calls a Main function which does the work, calling private sub-functions within.

An example is `Remove-ContentLine.ps1` which just spits out the contents of a file or piped input except for lines matching some pattern.

So they're like little "function-scripts".

Is there any way I can aggregate these scripts into a module while also keeping them exactly as they are in files?

Edit

If your hunch is that its easier to just copy paste and refactor them into a `psm1` then just say ;)

Comment: Try reading all files in a loop, extract function names, execute via dot-sourcing, then do `Export-ModuleMember` with the extracted names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Is there any way I can aggregate these scripts into a module while
>   also keeping them exactly as they are in files?

But I am certain that is **not** what you really want. If so, then **all** of your code will immediately execute when you load the module! Rather, I think what you want is that each of your scripts should be contained within a function; that group of functions is then loaded when you import the module; and you can then execute any of your functions on demand.

The process is very straightforward, and I have written an extensive article on just how to do that ([Further Down the Rabbit Hole: PowerShell Modules and Encapsulation](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/)) but I will summarize here:

(1) Edit each file to wrap the entire contents into a function and conclude with exporting the function. I would suggest name the function based on the file name. Thus, Remove-ContentLine.ps1 should now look like this:

```
function Remove-ContentLine()
{
    # original content of Remove-ContentLine.ps1 here
}
Export-ModuleMember Remove-ContentLine
```

(2) Decide on a name for your module and create a directory of that name. Let's call it `MyModule`. Within the `MyModule` directory, create a subdirectory to place all your .ps1 files; let's call that `ScriptCmdlets`.

(3) Create a module file `MyModule.psm1` within `MyModule` whose contents will be exactly this:

```
Resolve-Path $PSScriptRoot\ScriptCmdlets\*.ps1 |
? { -not ($_.ProviderPath.Contains(".Tests.")) } |
% { . $_.ProviderPath }
```

Yes, every module (.psm1) file I write contains that identical code!

(4) Create a module manifest `MyModule.psd1` within `MyModule` using the `New-ModuleManifest` cmdlet.

Then to use your module, just use Import-Module. But I urge you to review my article for more details to gain a better understanding of the process.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can if the scripts already executing something ("main"). If they just expose a function like `Remove-ContentLine` for the `Remove-ContentLine.ps1` you could dot source all the scripts in a single script to aggregate them or use the `ScriptsToProcess = @()` section when working with a module manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to refactor the functions from within each .ps1 into a proper module.  It should be essentially just copy/pasting the scripts into a single .psm1 file and creating a .psd1 for it.  Be sure to check for and properly handle anything that is set in the script or global scopes, and there are no naming conflicts between functions.

If you have Sapien PowerShell Studio, there is a 'New Module from Functions' option in the File menu which would help automate the bulk of this for you.